# How can I write a regular expression for this in android?

Tags: android, regex

I am having a string(number) with special characters. I want to search for a sub-string(comprising of digits only) & also I want to detect the starting index & ending index of matching sub-string in the string.
For example: main string:   **(+91)-1231212 1231**
Sub-string to search: **1212**

Currently I am using the following code to do this but in place of **1212**,it searched for **12312**. For other cases, it works fine.

```
   String sss0 = "1212";
   String  sss1 =  "(+91)-1231212 1231";

    sss0 = sss0.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");

    System.out.println("*************************"+sss0);

    String ptn = "" + sss0.charAt(0);
    for(int jj=0; jj<sss0.length()-1; jj++){

        ptn += "[^" + sss0.charAt(jj) + sss0.charAt(jj+1) + "]*?" + sss0.charAt(jj+1);

    }
         System.out.println("ptn: " + ptn);

    Pattern p300 = Pattern.compile(ptn);

    Matcher m300 = p300.matcher(sss1);

    if(m300.find()){
        System.out.println("start, stop: " + m300.start() + "," + (m300.end()-1 ));
        System.out.println("substring: " + sss1.substring(m300.start(), m300.end()));
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 9 questions, 0% accepted... no thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `indexOf()`?

Comment: Hi fge, thanks for reply. Actually I have to ignore special characters in the main string during searching for the sub-string.

Comment: Hi fge, String  sss1 =  "(+91)-1231212 1231"; for reference only, if we consider sss1 = "(+91)-1-2312-1-2 1231"

Comment: Hi fge, it should search for "12-1-2" in main string

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int start = sss1.indexOf(sss0);
if(start != -1) {  
   System.out.println("Start : " + start);
   System.out.println("End : " + start.length()); //maybe add +1 here depending on what you mean by end index.
}
```

You can also put this in a loop to find all occurences of the substring.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
pattern = ""
foreach char c in sss0:
    pattern += c + "[^0-9]*"

found_substring = match(pattern, sss1)
```

the idea being to intersperse the literal characters you're looking for with the pattern that you're willing to skip over.